# GridView with DropDownList throws exception in Edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my full grid

```
 <div id="grid">
    <asp:GridView ID="gridProduct"  runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
    ShowFooter="true" 
    onrowcancelingedit="gridProduct_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowdeleting="gridProduct_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gridProduct_RowEditing" 
    onrowupdating="gridProduct_RowUpdating" 
    onrowcommand="gridProduct_RowCommand"
    onrowdatabound="gridProduct_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ToolTip="Update" Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="buttonCancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" ToolTip="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit"/>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Delete"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonAdd" runat="server" Text="Ajouter" CommandName="AddNew" ToolTip="Add new User" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
            </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#Piece">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownListPartsEdit" DataTextField="Nom" DataValueField="ID_AchatTemplate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Piece") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelItemPiece" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Piece") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownListPartsFooter" runat="server" DataTextField="Nom" DataValueField="ID_AchatTemplate">
            </asp:DropDownList>   

            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxPiece" runat="server"/>--%>
            <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fieldValidPiece" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBoxPiece" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>--%>
            </FooterTemplate> 

             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Series">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxEditSeries" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Series") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelItemSeries" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Series") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxSeries" runat="server"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fieldValidSeries" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBoxSeries" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>
            </FooterTemplate> 

             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Revision">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxEditRevision" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Rev") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelItemRevision" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Rev") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxRevision" runat="server"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fieldValidRevision" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBoxRevision" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>
            </FooterTemplate> 

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firmware">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxEditFirmware" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Firmware") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelItemFirmware" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Firmware") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxFirmware" runat="server"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fieldValidFirmware" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBoxFirmware" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>
            </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField> 

           </Columns> 
    </asp:GridView>
```

This is my method event for editing. First I try to bind my dropDownList but I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
       protected void gridProduct_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {



        ClientParts getclient = new ClientParts();

        ClientPartsSearchCriteria criteria = new ClientPartsSearchCriteria();


      ((DropDownList)gridProduct.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("dropDownListPartsEdit")).DataSource = getclient.Get(criteria);


        ((DropDownList)gridProduct.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("dropDownListPartsEdit")).DataBind();


        gridProduct.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        PsaDataSet psaList = (PsaDataSet)ViewState["psaList"];
        BindGrid(psaList, false);

    }
```

I don't understand why "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." from this line

```
((DropDownList)gridProduct.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("dropDownListPartsEdit")).DataSource = getclient.Get(criteria);
```

Comment: Which line of code does the exception occur on?  Do you have debugging enabled?

Comment: ((DropDownList)gridProduct.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("dropDownListPartsEdit")).DataSource = getclient.Get(criteria);

Comment: If I change the drop down to a texBox this work well....

Comment: what is being returned by get client.Get(criteria) , list of t?

Comment: Data table from a dataSEt filled by a stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to Bind my drop Down in this onrowdatabound="gridProduct_RowDataBound">!!

Answer (score 0):

`((DropDownList)gridProduct.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("dropDownListPartsEd‌​it")).DataSource = getclient.Get(criteria)`

This is a pretty unsafe line of code.  First, you are assuming your `ClientParts.Get()` method returns proper data, and second, you are assuming the `FindControl()` is finding your DropDownList properly.  In order to isolate which part is failing, split the line into several lines of code, and add null checking.

My c# is rusty, but it should be something like this (assuming `ClientParts.Get()` returns `DataTable`):

```
(DropDownList)ddlParts = ((DropDownList)gridProduct.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("dropDownListPartsEd‌​it"));
if (ddlParts != null)
{
    (DataTable)dtParts = getclient.Get(criteria);
    if (dtParts != null)
    {
        ddlParts.DataSource = dtParts;
        ddlParts.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Edit: The problem is during this event, you can't reference EditItemTemplate controls with GridView.Rows[index].FindControl().  Using this will access controls in the ItemTemplate.  I'm not sure what the workaround is though since I have never tried to databind controls in templates in this way.   Maybe you should consider using an ObjectDataSource?

Comment: ddlParts.DataSource = dtParts; = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: DropDownList ddlParts = ((DropDownList)gridProduct.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("dropDownListPartsEd‌​it"));  In this situation ddlParts=NUll